# How to do meta_query with ACF checkbox values as they store themselves as arrays?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type "Product", I have created 4 checkbox option for a field "Select Category", User can select multiple option at a time. For Some reason I am not using taxonomy to classify products.

So when I do meta_query, it do not result anything. Basically, I have selected, category for every product in the custom post type "Product", but ACF store it's checkbox value in array, and the meta_query can't search that array as a whole. However it can search from an array. My code is as follows:

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'fproduct',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'select_product_categories',
            'value'   =>  array('Indoor Games', 'Property Management'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);

// query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "<pre>"; print_r($wp_query); echo "</pre>"; die;
```

So how can I search so that checkbox can work, also I can not get the checkbox value on a template, as it for post type for different products.

Comment: acf store check box like this : ["Indoor Games","Property Management"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved my problem as the checkbox is stored in searialized array, so instead of 'IN', 'LIKE' will work, so here goes the query -

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'fproduct',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'select_product_categories',
            'value'   =>  array('"Indoor Games"', '"Property Management"'),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: This doesn't work since 'LIKE' can only be used with strings. WP throws a fatal error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: addcslashes(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given in /wp-includes/class-wpdb.php:1562`

Answer (score 0):

In ACF checkbox, what value have you set?
Furthermore, using the IN operator, it does not work in these cases. Just try using the LIKE operator:

```
"compare" => "LIKE".
```

However, it is a totally wrong way to create a taxonomy in Wordpress, because in this way, you have to restructure all the queries and the system is much less powerful, because the database tables do not have relations between them.